# How to employ cache busting with aiohtttp and jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2, aiohttp

The documentation for aiohttp states:

When you want to enable cache busting, parameter `append_version` can be set to `True`

```
web.static('/prefix', path_to_static_folder, append_version=True)
```

(from [here](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#static-file-handling))

My question is, how do I inject the version query into the resulting HTML?

For e.g. I have:

```
<img class="logo" src="/path_to/static/images/logo.png">
```

in the jinja main layout template.

In the resulting HTML, I want:

```
<img class="logo" src="/path_to/static/images/logo.png?v=some-hash-value">
```

but as yet, perhaps not surprisingly, the src remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've found is to use aiohttp-jinja2. Many thanks to Dreamsorcerer there for putting me on the right road.

```
import aiohttp_jinja2

app = web.Application()
aiohttp_jinja2.setup(
    app,
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(Path(__file__).parent / "templates"),
)

app.add_routes(
    [
        web.static(
            "/static",
            Path(__file__).parent / "static",
            name="static",
            append_version=True,
        ),
    ]
)
```

in the app setup, and then to use that named `static` route in a template via the [`url()` global](https://aiohttp-jinja2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#default-globals)

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('static', filename='stylesheets/main.css') }}">
```